# Einstein Analytics : Dashboard Problem

Tags: einstein-analytics

Error IS : "  This widget can't be displayed because there is a problem with its source step:
Maximum Concurrent Analytics Queries for Orgs has been exceeded. Current value is 1, and the limit is 1  ".

We have created dashboard on which there are 5 charts and one global filter panel. when we create the dashboard first time and run first time then it shows all the data. after that it randomly shows the data in some chart. And shows the above error for the charts which we create on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this issue. Actually its an org limit issue. We had raised the complaint to salesforce, & it increased the limits of the org.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you data  is still there and please refresh  the dashboard and this may not working due to:
1-Because of you global filter not working 
2-The dataset is not there anymore
3-Make sure your Step is still there and valid

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply. I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: Dataset is still there. I also delete all the global filters but still it randomly shows the data. I want to show all the data in the dashboard which contains 5 chart. On creating first time only, it shows the data. Please provide some proper solution. When we create the lens , it shows the lens data. Every time. Only dashboard data is randomly shown.